Is type narrowing possible based on a function's return value?
I'm trying to achieve type narrowing that's based on a function's return value rather than a property.
The basic way to narrow based on a field works like this:
interface AFoo {
    type: "A"
    specificA();
}

interface BFoo {
    type: "B"
}

var a: AFoo | BFoo = null as any;

if (a.type === 'A') {
    a.specificA();
}

And this works like a charm, based on the union type and type's value, TS knows how to narrow the type of the object inside the conditional.
I'm trying to do something supposedly similar, like this:
interface AFoo {
    getType(): "A";
    specificA();
}

interface BFoo {
    getType(): "B";
}

var a: AFoo | BFoo = null as any;

if (a.getType() === 'A') {
    a.specificA();
}

Weirdly enough, TS is smart enough to offer auto-correct and know that getType() returns "A" or "B", but the type narrowing isn't kicking in, and a is still of type AFoo | BFoo inside the conditional statement.
Am I missing something here?
As a side note: I can't change the getType() to a field since it's actually a Java class passed into a JS environment.

Maybe as a workaround - can you wrap these classes? I get that it's supposedly some foreign object but if you can do something like an adaptor that exposes a getter for the getType(), then that bypasses the issue. But I'm not sure if that's possible in your situation.

@VLAZ I wish i could do that. If i could add code, I'd have a thousand diifferent workarounds, unfortunately I have a Java class and I'm just writing definitions in d.ts file.

Well, worth a shot (to suggest) I guess. It's indeed a bit weird that unions don't discriminate on the return value of a method. I can only guess it's a missing feature. Probably because it's almost never needed...except for foreign objects like this. And the getType() is standard practice in Java, not in JS/TS. Maybe the only option is a custom type guard but I understand why you'd want "regular" narrowing first.

Yes, it's a missing feature, requested as ms/TS#49771. If you're just wtriting .d.ts files then there's not much you can do other than tell library consumers to use a type guard function. If I were faced with this problem I'd provide my own library to wrap the suboptimal one, but that's out of scope here. So, how should we proceed here? It seems the answer to the question, as asked, is "no this is impossible" with a link to ms/TS#49771. Would that fully address it? If so I'll write that answer; otherwise, what's mising?

As @jcalz wrote, it's not a feature of TS unfortunately, I had to work with a BE developer to change the Java code (which wasn't optimal).
Thanks to everyone who helped!

You can use another function to validate your logic:
function isA(value: AFoo | BFoo): value is AFoo {
  if (value.getType() === 'A') {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

if (isA(a)) {
  a.specificA();
}


I would consider to modify the classes though:
Playground
interface AFoo {
    getType(): "A";
    get type(): ReturnType<AFoo['getType']>;
    specificA(): void
}

interface BFoo {
    get type(): ReturnType<BFoo['getType']>;
    getType(): "B";
}

class AFoo{
  getType(){ return 'A'};
  specificA(){console.log('A')};
}

Object.defineProperties(AFoo.prototype, {type: {get(){ return this.getType() }}});

const a: AFoo | BFoo = new AFoo;

if (a.type === 'A') {
    a.specificA();
}

